# Excel Odata Queries

Tags: excel, odata

I have created a Odata service in .net that handles Odata queries and I am running an excel doc connecting to the odata source.

I have added a condition that will not allow a odata feed to succeed if there is no aditional query (I.E. nothing else after the ?...) this is because the data set is to large without adidional queries reducing it.

My query is as follows
http://[MyLocalHost]/odata/Defect?$filter=[MyColumn] eq '[Value]'&$filter=[MyColumn] gt DateTimeOffset'[Value]'

It does not matter what the columns or values are in this case.
When i run the query in Fiddler or a web browser i get results back without any issue.
However if i use Excel i get errors relating to me not passing in aditional query options.

When i debug the solution i find that excel is running the query twice.
Once with my query " ?$filter=[MyColumn] eq '[Value]'&$filter=[MyColumn] gt DateTimeOffset'[Value]' " and then again with the query set as an empty string?

My question is, why does excel do this when fiddler and browsers do not?
and
Can i stop excel from doing this? if so how?

Comment: Please share your excel code which you use for your query, otherwise we can't find the problem.

Comment: This is the Odata Query
http://[MyLocalHost]/odata/Defect?$filter=[MyColumn] eq '[Value]'&$filter=[MyColumn] gt DateTimeOffset'[Value]'

The particulars of MyLocalHost, MyColumn and Value are not relavent to the issue.
The query runs fine in Fiddler and Direct into a browser so the query is not the proplem.

The OP asks why Excel would make two calls to the Odata server when you make this query when no other OData medium does.

Again the Odata servis works as expected it is Excel that is breaking it.